# How to eliminate vars in a Scala class?

Tags: scala

I have written the following Scala class based on a corresponding Java class: The result is not good. It still looks Java-like, is replete with vars, is very long, and is not idiomatic Scala in my opinion.

I am looking to shrink this piece of code, eliminate the vars and the @BeanHeader stuff.

Here is my code:

```
    import scala.collection.immutable.Map 

     class ReplyEmail {

     private val to: List[String] = List()   
     private val toname: List[String] = List()
     private var cc: ArrayList[String] = new ArrayList[String]()

    @BeanProperty
    var from: String = _

    private var fromname: String = _

    private var replyto: String = _

    @BeanProperty
    var subject: String = _

    @BeanProperty
    var text: String = _

    private var contents: Map[String, String] = new scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[String, String]()

    @BeanProperty
    var headers: Map[String, String] = new scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[String, String]()

    def addTo(to: String): ReplyEmail = {
      this.to.add(to)
      this
    }

    def addTo(tos: Array[String]): ReplyEmail = {
      this.to.addAll(Arrays.asList(tos:_*))
      this
    }

    def addTo(to: String, name: String): ReplyEmail = {
      this.addTo(to)
      this.addToName(name)
    }

    def setTo(tos: Array[String]): ReplyEmail = {
      this.to = new ArrayList[String](Arrays.asList(tos:_*))
      this
    }

    def getTos(): Array[String] = {
      this.to.toArray(Array.ofDim[String](this.to.size))
    }

    def getContentIds(): Map[_,_] = this.contents

    def addHeader(key: String, `val`: String): ReplyEmail = {
      this.headers + (key -> `val`)
      this
    }

     def getSMTPAPI(): MyExperimentalApi = new MyExperimentalApi
      }

   }
```

=---------------------

I appreciate any help in accomplishing this goal. 
**Updated Code**

I made some small changes to the code, like introducing an Option[String] instead of a String

```
case class ReplyEmail(
  to: List[String] = Nil,
  toNames: List[String] = Nil,
  cc: List[String],
  from: String,
  fromName: String,
  replyTo: String,
  subject: String,
  text: String,
  contents: Map[String, String] = Map.empty,
  headers: Map[String, String] = Map.empty) {
  def withTo(to: String): ReplyEmail = copy(to = this.to :+ to)
  def withTo(tos: List[String]): ReplyEmail = copy(to = this.to ++ to)
  def withTo(to: Option[String], name: Option[String]) = copy(to = this.to :+ to, toNames = toNames :+ name)

  def setTo(tos: List[String]): ReplyEmail = copy()
  def withHeader(key: String, value: String) = copy(headers = headers + (key  -> value))
  def smtpAPI = new MyExperimentalApi
```

}

---

Now, the only problem I face is in this line:
   The error is: type mismatch: found: List[java.io.Serializable] required: List[String]

```
def withTo(to: Option[String], name: Option[String]) = copy(to = this.to :+ to, toNames = toNames :+ name)
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: You are calling `(List[String])  :+ (Option[String])`. You get `List[Serializable]` because that's what `String` and `Option[String]` have in common. You probably wanted to add the item to the list if it's defined, otherwise leave the list as-is. Here's how you might do that: `to.foldLeft(this.to) { _ :+ _ }`

Comment: Also you could probably refactor your to/toNames and from/fromName relationship into a `case class EmailAddress(address: String, name: Option[String])`

Comment: Okay, based on your suggestion this is what I did:                                            def withTo(to: Option[String], name: Option[String]) = copy(to.foldLeft(this.to ){_ :+ _}, to.foldLeft(this.toNames){_ :+ _})                        Does it look right?

Comment: I updated my code based on what you said: "                                                       def withTo(to: Option[String], name: Option[String]) =                      copy(toList = to.foldLeft(this.toList ){_ :+ _}, toNames = to.foldLeft(this.toNames){_ :+ _})                               Is this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make it a case class.

```
case class ReplyEmail(
  to: List[String] = Nil,
  toNames: List[String] = Nil,
  cc: List[String],
  from: String,
  fromName: String,
  replyTo: String,
  subject: String,
  text: String,
  contents: Map[String, String] = Map.empty,
  headers: Map[String, String] = Map.empty) {

  def withTo(to: String) = copy(to = this.to :+ to)

  def withTo(to: List[String] = copy(to = this.to ++ to)

  def withTo(to: String, name: String) = copy(to = this.to :+ to, toNames = toNames :+ name)

  def withHeader(key: String, value: String) = copy(headers = headers + (key -> value))

  def smtpAPI = new MyExperimentalApi

}
```